# Calling smart contract function repeatedly/Iteratively on Single Transaction

Tags: solidity, web3js

Hello Is it possible to call the solidity function repeatedly on a Single Tx?

If Possible with the contract, Then How to write that contract?

Comment: Yes, but using a contract to make the calls.

Comment: But How do I write that contract? Could you explain with code?

Comment: It is a more advanced use of solidity, the `address.call()` command.